# Como gerar uma variável com valor aleatório em C

Tags: c

Boa noite galera.
Bom, estou fazendo um curso de programação em C e nesse curso tem um desafio, criar um jogo de jokenpô.

Comecei fazendo o parte do código do jogo e tal e a parte que o usuário escolhe qual objeto do jokenpo vai usar funcionou, porém não estou conseguindo fazer uma variável receber o valor aleatório gerado pela função srand.

Desculpa pela dúvida galera, estou começando faz pouquíssimo tempo haha desde já agradeço.

Comment: Na biblioteca `stdlib.h`, use a função `random`. Gere antes uma semente e alimente a `srandom`.

Comment: Se este tip ode pergunta estivesse no escopo teria várias respostas já postadas antes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2brandom?tab=Votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa abaixo gera 5 números pseudo-aleatórios entre 1 e 10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int num, i;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        /* gera um número pseudo-aleatório entre 1 e 10 */
        num = rand() % 10 + 1;
        /* faça alguma coisa com o número*/
        printf("%dº número gerado: %d\n", i, num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note que a função srand gera apenas a semente da sequencia de números aleatórios.

Comment: então basicamente é possivel atribuir a varável o valor gerado pelo srand

Comment: Mto obrigado, vou implementar isso e ver se dá certo